# @IBActions for buttons are Disconnected when Added to Code - Swift, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am currently experiencing a problem in Xcode 8 where, throughout my entire project, whenever I attempt to add an IBAction to a button, the action is disconnected (open circle) in the code.

This problem only occurs in one project; I have tested other projects and the actions are added correctly (closed circle).

Any assistance in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you run the app and tested if they are not connected? Sometimes it only looks like the action is not connected but it actually is

Comment: I tested the app several times, both on device and in simulator, crashes each time with an NSException.

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 8 please check your action method as it

```
@IBAction func PrintAgain(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

before sender add _ 
because if you remove _ from function the xcode add WithSender automatic    for function name

Comment: Adding this underscore presents an 'extraneous argument error'.

Comment: not error it's warning only but if you make a simple app and drag action from button not warning appear